# Is WCF translation to SQL supported in Linqpad?

Tags: wcf, linqpad

I am typing a WCF Expression but I don't find a way in Linqpad to get the SQL Query.

For example I typed a expression Customer.Take (100) and Execute the expression.
After that I can see the tabs: "Results", "lambda", "Request Log" and "IL" below the expression text window but no SQL tab.
When I go to the "Request Log" tab I can see the URL

```
https://<url>/Customer()?$top=100.
```

I also see a "Analyze SQL" option on the right.
I select "Open as SQL Query in New tab" but I get the same URL displayed on the new tab and no SQL.
Is this supported in Linqpad or do I have to find another way to capture the SQL query that resulted from executing the WCF request?

Is this supported in linqpad?

If not supported do you have any other suggestions. Are there any other tools that support this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WCF Data Services queries do not translate to SQL; they translate to web requests. That's why the SQL tab disappears and a "Request Log" tab appears.

Edit: see also: http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/comment/1278#Comment_1278